# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_name'

Tags: python, module

I just made a release on a personal library called [eule](https://pypi.org/project/eule/). The tests passed locally and remotely, cool! However, when I tried to import it on a project, BOOM, the error below appeared:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eule'
```

I did not make any modification in regard library accessment or anything like that to receive this behavior. Anyhow, I will be thankful if you take a look and suggest alterations which may make the library accessible.

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Comment: What is the exact directory path where the library is installed?

Comment: This is the module repository: https://github.com/trouchet/eule

Comment: That's not what I asked.  On the computer where this error occurred, where is that module installed?

Comment: When I install, it sayd "/home/brunolnetto/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages". But on command run "ls /home/brunolnetto/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages", it returns, among others, folder "eule-1.0.0.dist-info".

Comment: I removed this folder and installed the module again. It worked! Thanks. :-)